# Regex for replacing spaces not between quotation marks

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to remove all **whitespaces** from a given string like this

```
const mystring = `
   This is an example string with 'single quotes' and "big quotes"!
   No that "this \" special \" " notation with escaped quotes should also not be matched
`;
```

that are not between quotes (`"` or `'`) to get something like this

```
const result = `Thisisanexamplestringwith'single quotes'and"big quotes"!Nothat"this \" special \" "notationwithescapedquotesshouldalsonotbematched`;
```

---

Some **better examples** that are easier to understand:

- `This is an example with "quotes and spaces"!` > `Thisisanexamplewith"quotes and spaces"!`
- `Second example for 'quotes and spaces'` > `Secondexamplefor'quotes and spaces'`
- `test "a \"b c \" d e"` > `testa \"b c \" d e"`

I guess the principle is easy to understand.

I want to replace via Regular Expression without additional javascript code. Since I haven't really worked with Regex much and I'm totally desperate after a full day on [Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/), I decided to ask for help on SO.

---

Any help how to go on would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance!

---

**What I've done so far**:

I'm pretty sure using Regex's Lookahead/Lookbehind matcher will do the job but I guess I'm not really using it as I should...

- \s(?<!") [image: regex #1]
- \s(?<="[^"].) [image: regex #2]
- \s+(?=(?:(?:\.|[^"\])*"(?:\.|[^"\])*")*) [image: regex #3]

Comment: Use `mystring.replace(/("[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*')|\s+/g, (x,y) => y || "" )`. However, you declared your string in a wrong way, use ``const mystring = String.raw`...`;``

Comment: Actually, even that regex above should be enhanced to avoid a match starting with an escaped quote. You won't be able to just use lookarounds here, because left- and right-hand delimiters are the same single characters.

Comment: Hi, just to make sure: do you realize your `mystring` and `result` contain no literal backslashes? I think you actually meant them to be there, so you need to define the string literals with `String.raw`.

Comment: Did my comments help?